# UIPageViewController custom PageControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

For a project I am working on I would like to modify the looks of the `UIPageControl` I found out that I could change some things with the `appearance` method on UIPageControl.

However I would like to change the dot size and spacing. Looking on the internet I came across [FXPageControl](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXPageControl). Which supports this.

Currently I am loading my `UIPageViewController` from `StoryBoard`. And it thus loads a "normal" `UIPageControl`. How can I make the `FXPageControl` be loaded instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
You can only don't show default `UIPageControl` and show & handle `FXPageControl` manually by yourself in code / xib